# Discord Bot - How to check roles in a DM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord v13 and I'm following the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions) here in order to verify if the user that sent a DM message to the bot has the `Admin` role or not.

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.member.roles.cache.has('role-id') {
    console.log('User is an admin')
  }
})
```

It works fine if I send a message to my bot from a channel, which is not what I want. I need the bot to check for the role when the user sends a DM to the bot. However, the `member` property returns `null` when I send a DM to the bot.

Is there something that I'm missing? Some intent or partial? These are my intents/partials so far:

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES],
  partials: ['CHANNEL']
});
```

I also tried to access the property `channel` to see if I could fetch the roles but no success. Any hints guys? I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me here. This is the message object that I get when the bot receives a DM:

```
<ref *1> Message {
channelId: 'channel-id',
guildId: null,
deleted: false,
id: '919665813525495879',
createdTimestamp: 1639335816509,
type: 'DEFAULT',
system: false,
content: '!get-comic',
author: User {
  id: '611561522673745931',
  bot: false,
  system: false,
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  username: 'deric',
  discriminator: '6024',
  avatar: '0277c05b2fe81cd286dc403b5e88c7ba',
  banner: undefined,
  accentColor: undefined
},
pinned: false,
tts: false,
nonce: '919665812787167232',
embeds: [],
components: [],
attachments: Collection(0) [Map] {},
stickers: Collection(0) [Map] {},
editedTimestamp: null,
reactions: ReactionManager { message: [Circular *1] },
mentions: MessageMentions {
  everyone: false,
  users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  roles: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  _members: null,
  _channels: null,
  crosspostedChannels: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  repliedUser: null
},
webhookId: null,
groupActivityApplication: null,
applicationId: null,
activity: null,
flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
reference: null,
interaction: null
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intents and partials look okay to me. However, in DMs the properties [`guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild), [`guildId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guildId), and [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) are `null`. You can see that by reading the docs.

If you know the guild ID, you can [fetch the member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) by its ID. You can get this user ID from `message.author`.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  // the ID of the guild the message.author is a member of
  let guildId = '630136153909678321';
  let roleId = '869192198029209314';

  try {
    let guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId);
    let member = await guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);

    if (member.roles.cache.has(roleId)) {
      console.log('User is an admin');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked